# Align vertically in div with other elements

Tags: css

So I'm trying to vertically align span element inside of div parent. Div parent got two children, div and span in question.

Image to demonstrate what I have and what I want [image]

Current mark up

```
<div class="agmtwr_container">
    <div class="agmtwr_shape_container">
        <span class="agmtwr_shape agmtwr_voted"></span>
        <span class="agmtwr_shape agmtwr_voted"></span>
        <span class="agmtwr_shape agmtwr_voted"></span>
        <span class="agmtwr_shape agmtwr_voted"></span>
        <span class="agmtwr_shape agmtwr_empty"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="agmtwr_vote_count">6 votes</span>
</div>
```

Original CSS (before any attempts to center)

```
.agmtwr_shape_container {display:inline-block;height:16px;width:80px}
.agmtwr_shape{padding:0px;margin:0px;display: inline-block; background-size: 100% 100%;width:16px;height: 16px;}
.agmtwr_empty {background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve"><polygon fill="#D0D0D0" points="10,0 13.1,6.6 20,7.6 15,12.8 16.2,20 10,16.6 3.8,20 5,12.8 0,7.6 6.9,6.6 "/></svg>');}
.agmtwr_voted {background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve"><polygon fill="#B8000A" points="10,0 13.1,6.6 20,7.6 15,12.8 16.2,20 10,16.6 3.8,20 5,12.8 0,7.6 6.9,6.6 "/></svg>');}
```

I have tried few suggested things with line-height, etc, but it just doesn't seem to work =/
I'd like to avoid table related solution.

Comment: please also include the css for this markup, especially for `.agmtwr_shape_container`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
.agmtwr_container span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use vertical align:

```
.agmtwr_container *{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Padding bottom,

```
.agmtwr_vote_count
{
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
```